# Assign Hyperlink cells to text cells in Excel using Macro

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink, cell

I have an Excel worksheet (Sheet1). It has two columns "A" and "B" and they are both of 12 cells (A1-A12, B1-B12). Column "A" contains names while the other contains hyperlinks.

What I need please, is a vba macro that will write column A values in a new column (D for example) and assign the hyperlinks (in column B) to them respectively. i.e. for example:

D1 = HYPERLINK(B1;A1)

which means that the cell D1 will contain the text in A1 which indicates to the hyperlink in B1.

I hope to get your help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why not just use your formula, and fill down to D12?

Answer (score 1):

Unless I've missed something, you answered this in your question? The below formula does this:

`=HYPERLINK(B1, A1)`

Comment: I know, but how to do it for all cells in the columns at once using a vba macro?
Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify your question please? Is there multiple hyperlinks or is it one hyperlink spread over 12 cells? If it is multiple hyperlinks (1 per row), you would just copy or drag the formula down without any need VBA

Comment: Worked like a charm. I didn't know that before.

Comment: Great to hear Ziyad. Please consider marking this as answered if it resolved your query.